# Telerik Modal Popup Size

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have an ASP.NET project using a Master form and Telrik AJAX controls. I use base list and edit controls to help keep the UI consistent. When an edit control is opened in a modal popup from the RadGrid the form is smaller than the control. Is there a way to force the window to the proper size, or at least manually set the size?

The base list control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ListBaseControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="BaseControls.ListBaseControl" %>
<div>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="uxBaseList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDeleteCommand="uxBaseList_DeleteCommand" 
        OnNeedDataSource="uxBaseList_NeedDataSource" Skin="WebBlue" OnItemDataBound="uxBaseList_ItemDataBound" >
        <MasterTableView EditMode="PopUp" CommandItemDisplay="Top"  >
            <EditFormSettings UserControlName="CustomerEditControl.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl" >
                <PopUpSettings Modal="true" />
                <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" ></EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</div>
```

The derived list control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShopListControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="ShopUI.ShopListControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="../BaseControls/ListBaseControl.ascx" TagName="ListBaseControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<uc1:ListBaseControl ID="uxShopList" runat="server" DataKeyFields="ShopId" DeleteButtonVisible="false" EditControlName="ShopEditTest.ascx" />
```

The base edit control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditBaseControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="BaseControls.EditBaseControl" %>
<div class="footer" >
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="uxSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="uxSave_Click" CommandName="Update" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
        <asp:Button ID="uxCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="uxCancel_Click" CommandName="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-danger"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="uxChangedBy" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="uxChangedDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The derived edit control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShopEditBoostrapTest.ascx.cs" Inherits="ShopUI.ShopEditTest" %>
<div class="container" style="height:500px;width:950px;">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: lightgray;">
        <div class="span12" style="background-color: lightblue;">Welcome to my web site</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: lightgray;">
        <div class="span4" style="background-color: lightcoral;">
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <caption>Span 4</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell (0, 0)</td>
                    <td>Cell (0, 1)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell (1, 0)</td>
                    <td>Cell (1, 1)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span8" style="background-color: lightpink;">Span 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

Method 1.

```
 <EditFormSettings>
                <PopUpSettings Width="700px" Height="700px" Modal="true" />
 </EditFormSettings>
```

Method 2.

ASPX

```
        <ClientSettings AllowRowsDragDrop="true">
            <ClientEvents OnPopUpShowing="PopUpShowing" />
        </ClientSettings>
```

JS

```
        var popUp;
        function PopUpShowing(sender, eventArgs) {
            popUp = eventArgs.get_popUp();
            popUp.style.width = "500px";
            popUp.style.height = "500px";
        }
```

Comment: It had no effect, but maybe I am adding the code into the wrong spot. I tried adding it above the first `<div>` tag in the derived control .ascx file.

Comment: I have updated my above code snippet. can you please try with 'method2'.

Comment: I found I had direct access to the PopUpSettings in the derived list control and used `if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                 uxShopList.RadGrid.MasterTableView.EditFormSettings.PopUpSettings.Width = 1040;
}`